export-policy with gcloud command
gcloud netapp volumes update nfs-demo-1 --location=us-west1 --storage-pool=STND-POOL01 --export-policy=allowed-clients=1.2.3.4,nfsv4=true,access-type=readonly
ERROR: gcloud crashed (KeyError): 'readonly'

Looks like the syntax not working https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/netapp/volumes/update
Question: how can i set export policy when creating a NetApp volume in GCP with the gcloud cmd? Or later update it with the gcloud cmd.
I read the official docs, but it didn't described the syntax properly
